# ADB devices lists no connected device

Tags: android, windows-8, adb

i have enabled usb debugging on my Nexus 7 (2013 model). But when i run `adb devices` command, the only devices listed are the running AVD emulators. Also i get no RSA fingerprint confirmation on my tablet.

I have properly installed the latest android sdk, and google usb drivers with it. Also in device manager i do not get any 'ADB Interface' option or such. The only place nexus 7 is listed is under 'Other Devices'.

When i plug the device in my friend's laptop everything works just fine, i get the RSA confirmation and everything. So the problem must be in my laptop.
I thought it could be bluestacks so i uninstalled it, and also deleted every occurrence of it from the registry. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Try switching the media type from `Media device (MTP)` to `Camera (PTP)`and then switch back again, it works for me sometimes.

Comment: yes i have done that too.. enabling one, switching to another, disabling both.. nothing has worked for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this. The problem was with my Google USB Drivers.
I tried deleting the package from SDK Manager and reinstalling it. But it didn't work.

So, I downloaded the drivers separately from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) then replaced the existing files (\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver). I got the RSA fingerprint message on my device.